# How does CATALINA_OPTS works in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am curious how does CATALINA_OPTS work in the background in Apache Tomcat? yes I know it executes on start and run of Tomcat and I add some parameters to be used by my program in it, And even I use it for long time add it to my VM parameters but not sure how it operates really.

For example isn't that possible to set those parameters say in Web.xml as context init parameters?

Comment: there are lots of properties in the file that I refer to using CATALINA_OPTS as -Dmy.properties.file

Comment: Many java programs accepts some way of accepting user values and pass to jvm, before it is created. An environment variable (_OPTS) is generally used.  For example ant, groovy...   While some parameters could be changed after the process is started, others  like memory setting easily configurable via such variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're just command-line options that the Tomcat startup scripts pass to the Java runtime executable when it starts. You can't change them at runtime since the server is already running.

Comment: thanks could you explain a bit more? whats the difference between context params? there are lots of properties in the file that I refer to using CATALINA_OPTS as -Dmy.properties.file

Comment: CATALINA_OPTS should be used for Java settings like memory (like -Xmx) and JVM global variables for things like XML parsers and such. Context parameters are specific to a single webapps and should be used for application settings. It might be better to put `my.properties.file` in a `context.xml` file and look it up at runtime using JNDI. http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/tomcat-jndi/tomcat-jndi.html

Answer (score 2):

Extending Zutty's answser a bit.  A running instances of Tomcat could be tweaked with [JMX.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html) .